# Questions about docker, nvidia-docker, cudnn and tensorflow

Tags: gpu, docker

I have some questions about cudnn and tensorflow-gpu docker image. here is what I did on my computer:

1. I installed `docker-CE`
2. I installed `nvidia-docker`
3. I pulled `tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter` image from docker hub.
4. I create one container with the following command:

   > ```
   > sudo docker create -ti --rumtime=nvidia -p 21001:22 -v
   > /home/project:/project tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter /bin/bash
   > ```
5. I start and get into the container, then I train my model which is built using Keras. but I get one error message---'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

It seems that the cudnn is not installed in my container. Does anybody know why it happened? Does tensorflow image does not include the cudnn library?